# I have all the permissions but it still shows permission denied - Linux Terminal

Tags: postgresql, permission-denied, tablespace

I am logged in as `postgres` user at location `/home/postgres`, I created a file `assignment` it has all the necessary permissions for `postgres` user
the file permissions looks like -

for `/home/postgres`

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 postgres postgres 4096 Jun  2 13:13 assignment
```

for `/home`

```
drwxr-xr-x  3 postgres   postgres   4096 Jun  2 13:18 postgres
```

Then I start the `psql` shell using command `psql` as `postgres`, I try to create new `TABLESPACE`

```
postgres=# CREATE TABLESPACE assignment
postgres-# OWNER postgres
postgres-# LOCATION '/home/postgres/assignment/';
```

But it gives permission denied error -

```
ERROR:  could not set permissions on directory "/home/postgres/assignment": Permission denied
```

I don't get it, please help I have an assignment to complete, Thanks.

Comment: A couple of things to _try_.   Try without the trailing slash after assignment.  Try without the OWNER clause.  Try `rmdir` the assignment folder, and create it again with `mkdir`, `chown`, `create tablespace` as per here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtablespace.html

Comment: As operating system user `postgres`, try running `chmod 0700 /home/postgres/assignment`. Do you get "permission denied"? Then fix that.

Comment: Thanks @GregHNZ for your kind suggestion but I already tried these methods.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe thanks for you suggestion but I already tried giving the postgres user full permissions using chmod.

Comment: That's not what I said.

Comment: PostgreSQL does **not** want full permissions on that directory. When you create the tablespace, it **reduces** the permissions. If *changing* the permissions fails, you get that error message. You have to make sure that the operating system user `postgres` is allowed to change the permissions on the directory.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe thanks now I understand, so I executed the command you previously mentioned `chmod 0700 /home/postgres/assigment` but same result. I understand you are saying to make sure `postgres` user is allowed to change permissions, where can I read more about it so I can solve it by myself, can you point me to some resource. Thanks for explaining it to me anyways.

Comment: Two possibilities come to my mind: 1) immutable file attribute (look for `i` in `lsattr /home/postgres/assignment`) 2) a weird file system (look at `mount`).